# how to read keras .h5 model from gcp storage bucket

Tags: python, keras, google-cloud-platform

I have a keras model saved in gcp bucket storage as h5 file, I used below code to read:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py
import gcsfs

FS = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="bucketname")
with FS.open(fn_model, 'rb') as model_file:
     model_gcs = h5py.File(model_file, 'r')
     myModel = load_model(model_gcs)
```

I got error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

I then tried:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import h5py
import gcsfs

FS = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="bucketname")
with FS.open(fn_model, 'rb', "utf-8") as model_file:
     model_gcs = h5py.File(model_file, 'r')
     myModel = load_model(model_gcs)
```

now error is `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

I tried someone's answer in stackoverflow as below:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
model_file = file_io.FileIO(fn_model, mode='rb')

temp_model_location = 'temp_model.h5'
temp_model_file = open(temp_model_location, 'wb')
temp_model_file.write(model_file.read())
temp_model_file.close()
model_file.close()
model = load_model(temp_model_location)
```

still got error: `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

I used gsutil to copy .h5 file to local drive, then tried load_model, but still error `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

what's the correct way to read .h5 Keras model from gcp storage bucket?

Comment: Which version of h5py are you using?

Comment: h5py version: 3.1.0

Comment: i guess you need to download model first then try to read.

Comment: is your script in VM or local machine?

Comment: script is in gcp VM.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same issue and would like to avoid the copy solution proposed by Rajith below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while loading model from bucket.This is what I did.

1. First you copy the model to a specific location in VM,lets say you copy to `/home/jupyter/project/` location
2. Load the copied model from local disk and delete copied file

---

```
import subprocess
import os

model_name = "model_file.h5"
subprocess.call(f"gsutil cp gs://bucket_name/model_path/{model_name} /home/jupyter/project/",shell=True)
myModel = load_model(f"/home/jupyter/project/{model_name}")
os.remove(f"/home/jupyter/project/{model_name}")
```

Comment: Thank you @Rajith Thennakoon, however, I did not get error from ```subprocess.call(...)``` but ```myModel=...``` got error: ```SavedModel file does not exist```

Comment: did you check the model is exist after copied and bucket path is correct?if script is in VM this should work.I used it few days ago without any issue.

Comment: No, model does not exist after copied.